# Manipulate results to display rows as columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables.
Table A contains a list of departments, there are 20 in total.

See image

[image]

Table B contains at least 1 row per department found in Table A, with some containing a few.

See image

[image]

What I want is a 3rd table created from A & B which basically lists every department and then the number of people who are full time and part time. If for example there is a department found in table b which only has a figure for either Full or Part time (an example of this is department D) then I want the table to display 0 (zero) instead of leaving this blank.

See image

[image]

Can anyone advise on this?

**EDIT**
If there is no for example 'Part time' for one of the Departments, that means that their part time staff count WILL be zero as a rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
select *
from (tableb) s
pivot (Max(staffno) for employee_class in ([Full Time],[Part Time])) p
```

Comment: This works, can you explain how I coalesce the Full Time & Part Time and also exmplain what the p at the end is doing?

Comment: How do you mean "coalesce" the full and part time? The `p` is just an alias for the pivoting.

Comment: See Itzik Ben-Gan's excellent article on Pivots; he covers many different ways to Pivot data. http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/pivoting-data

Comment: @SelectDistinct  select DeptName ,[FullTime] = COALESCE([FullTime],0),[PartTime] = COALESCE([PartTime],0) from....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A.DEPTNAME, 
       sum(case when B.EMPLOYEE_CLASS='Full time' then B.STAFF_NO else 0) as FullTimeNo,
       sum(case when B.EMPLOYEE_CLASS='Part time' then B.STAFF_NO else 0) as PartTimeNo,
from TabA A
join TabB B on A.DEPTNAME=B.DEPTNAME
group by A.DEPTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  A.DEPTNAME,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA A2 INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.TableAID = A2.TableAID WHERE B.EMPLOYEE_CLASS = 'Full time' AND A2.TableAID = A.TableAID) FullTimeNo,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA A2 INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.TableAID = A2.TableAID WHERE B.EMPLOYEE_CLASS = 'Part time' AND A2.TableAID = A.TableAID) PartTimeNo
FROM
  TABLEA
```