# Groupby using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this table:

```
Person  Job
PersonA XX
PersonA XX
PersonA XX
PersonB XX
PersonB XX
PersonB YY
PersonB ZZ
PersonC XX
PersonC XX
PersonA XX
PersonA YY
PersonB ZZ
...
```

Now, I want the output to be something like this:

```
Job PersonA PersonB Person C
XX  4       2       2
YY  1       1       0
ZZ  0       2       0
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person,
                       (SELECT COUNT(Job)
                        FROM dbo.TableName
                        GROUP BY Job)
FROM dbo.ExcelImport
```

No luck :(

Comment: Could you not address this in your `table` or normalizing data?

Comment: Try looking at the pivot function, some links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031846/manipulate-results-to-display-rows-as-columns

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074939/get-rows-as-columns-sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud try something like this:

```
select
    Job
    ,SUM(case when Person = 'PersonA'
        then
            1
        else
            0
    end) as 'PersonA'
    ,SUM(case when Person = 'PersonB'
        then
            1
        else
            0
    end) as 'PersonB'
    ,SUM(case when Person = 'PersonC'
        then
            1
        else
            0
    end) as 'PersonC'
from
    TableName
group by
    Job
```

Comment: Awesome! Thats what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

It is easy task for `pivot` operator:

```
select *
from (select Job as Job2, * from [TableName]) t
    pivot (count(Job2) for Person in ([PersonA],[PersonB],[PersonC])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot too

```
select * from per
pivot (count(job)  for job in ([xx],[yy],[zz]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if persons are is fixed

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
PIVOT
(
    COUNT([Person]) FOR [Person] IN ([PersonA],[PersonB],[PersonC])
) p
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a51da/1)

If persons vary then try this dynamic query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Person]) 
                    from Table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT [Job],' + @cols + ' 
             FROM
             (
                Select *
                FROM Table1
             ) T
             PIVOT
             (
                COUNT([Person])
                FOR [Person] IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) pvt '

EXECUTE(@query);
```